# Does Mercurial support CRecord interactive commit on Windows?

Tags: windows, mercurial

I've added these lines to mercurial.ini:

```
[ui]
interface = curses
interface.chunkselector = curses
```

But it keeps showing the interface in this (record extension) style:

```
examine changes to '<filename>'? [Ynesfdaq?]
```

I would like to use the [crecord extension](https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/crecord/src/default/) type interface because I want to select individual lines to commit instead of chunks and it seems easier to use. Is it possible to use the crecord extension on Windows?

[Ncurses support has been added](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5512), and the record extension uses colors. The hg version installed is 4.7+11-cee9043c7dba.